# Django - Database image from models

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Is there any free app to generate database image schema from all models from all apps, as .jpg for example? I need image with tables and relations shown.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`graph_models`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html) from [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) should [do](https://www.flickr.com/photos/filipecorreia/5627410410/in/photostream/) what you want.